# Replacement scalamock-scalatest-support in scala version 2.13

Tags: scala, dependencies

While upgrading the scala version from 2.12 to 2.13. There is the dependency "scalamock-scalatest-support" which is not supported in scala version 2.13 (checked from this page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalamock/scalamock-scalatest-support). Is there anyone know which lib can be replaced with the un-supported dependency "scalamock-scalatest-support"

Best Regards,

Comment: If they didn't publish `2.13` version it doesn't necessarily mean your code won't work with `2.12`. You can try and see by forcing ...2.12 scala version in your SBT/Maven, etc build script.

Comment: No it won't, Scala versions 2.12 and 2.13 are not compatible

Answer (score 1):

That dependency is no longer needed starting in Scalamock version 4.0.x which is when support for Scala 2.13 started.

See the "Upgrading from ScalaMock Version 3.x" section of the [Scalamock installation page](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/installation/) for detail.